# ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher() vs ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()

Tags: java, servlets

**why**

> getRequestDispatcher(String path) of
>   the ServletRequest interface cannot
>   extend outside the current servlet
>   context

**where as**

> getRequestDispatcher(String path) of
>   the ServletContext can use the
>   getContext(String uripath) method to
>   obtain RequestDispatcher for resources
>   in foreign contexts.

**and how??**

Please help

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you use an absolute path such as (`"/index.jsp"`), there is no difference.

If you use relative path, you must use `HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()`. `ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher()` doesn't allow it.

For example, if you receive your request on `http://example.com/myapp/subdir`,

```
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

Will forward the request to the page `http://example.com/myapp/subdir/index.jsp`.

In any case, you can't forward request to a resource outside of the context.

Comment: For "can't forward request to a resource outside of the context", I would clarify which context is being referred to here. I'm knee deep in an issue at the moment and I have a context where even after getting another context I can't seem to forward a request to it and this answer makes me wonder if it's actually impossible and why J2EE makes simple stuff so damn hard.

Answer (score 2):

The request method `getRequestDispatcher()` can be used for referring to local servlets within single webapp.

Servlet context based `getRequestDispatcher()` method can used of referring servlets from other web applications deployed on **SAME** server.

Comment: The latter is not directly true. You'd need to get the `ServletContext` of the other webapp first by `ServletContext#getContext()`.

Comment: What directories are you talking about and where does it say which directories they are.

Answer (score 1):

request.getRequestDispatcher(“url”) means the dispatch is relative to the current HTTP request.Means this is for chaining two servlets with in the same web application
Example

```
RequestDispatcher reqDispObj = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
```

getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(“url”) means the dispatch is relative to the root of the ServletContext.Means this is for chaining two web applications with in the same server/two different servers

Example

```
RequestDispatcher reqDispObj = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ContextRoot/home.jsp");
```

Comment: What do you mean "relative to the current HTTP request" how would I find the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that your first question is simply a matter of scope. The ServletContext is a much more broad scoped object (the whole servlet context) than a ServletRequest, which is simply a single request. You might look to the Servlet specification itself for more detailed information.

As to how, I am sorry but I will have to leave that for others to answer at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Context is stored at the application level scope where as request is stored at page level i.e to say

Web Container brings up the applications one by one and run them inside its JVM. It stores a singleton object in its jvm where it registers anyobject that is put inside it.This singleton is shared across all applications running inside it as it is stored inside the JVM of the container itself.

However for requests, the container creates a request object that is filled with data from request and is passed along from one thread to the other (each thread is a new request that is coming to the server), also request is passed to the threads of same application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will understand it through these examples below.

**Source code structure:**

```
/src/main/webapp/subdir/sample.jsp
/src/main/webapp/sample.jsp
```

Context is: `TestApp` 
So the entry point: `http://yourhostname-and-port/TestApp`

**Forward to RELATIVE path:**

Using `servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("sample.jsp")`:

```
http://yourhostname-and-port/TestApp/subdir/fwdServlet  ==> \subdir\sample.jsp
http://yourhostname-and-port/TestApp/fwdServlet ==> /sample.jsp
```

Using `servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("sample.jsp")`:

```
http://yourhostname-and-port/TestApp/subdir/fwdServlet ==> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path sample.jsp does not start with a "/" character
http://yourhostname-and-port/TestApp/fwdServlet ==> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path sample.jsp does not start with a "/" character
```

**Forward to ABSOLUTE path:**

Using `servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/sample.jsp")`:

```
http://yourhostname-and-port/TestApp/subdir/fwdServlet  ==> /sample.jsp
http://yourhostname-and-port/TestApp/fwdServlet ==> /sample.jsp
```

Using `servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/sample.jsp")`:

```
http://yourhostname-and-port/TestApp/subdir/fwdServlet ==> /sample.jsp
http://yourhostname-and-port/TestApp/fwdServlet ==> /sample.jsp
```