# How to call events on multiple button in same jsp file?

Tags: jsp, events, servlets

I am working with jsp/servlet and following MVC architecture. I have one jsp form which has 4 button.
In that I have to calculate net amount on entered product quantity and product rate and so on.

So I want calculate net amount and needs to be set in textbox when I clicked on button.

I have tried by checking button name and dispatcher but its doent work and gives NullPointerException.

Here is my part of servlet code.

```
        String a=request.getParameter("act");
        if (a.equals("Calculate Net Amount "))
        {
            System.out.println("success4.......");

            int pquantity=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("prodquantity"));
            double prate=Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("prodrate"));              
            double n=pquantity * prate;

            request.setAttribute("neta", n);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "Sales.jsp" );  
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);  

        }
```

Comment: Is your dispatcher object null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `request.getRequestDispatcher` instead of getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher. For example:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

Apparently `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher` doesn't allow relative path.
For more information see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411114/servletcontext-getrequestdispatcher-vs-servletrequest-getrequestdispatcher).