# Forwarding request from one servlet to a servlet in a different war

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, websphere

I have an EAR1. This EAR1 has a WAR1 inside it, with a context of '/war1'. This war1 has a servlet with url-mapping of '/servlet1' inside it.

On the same instance of WebSphere, I have an EAR2. This EAR2 has a WAR2 inside it, with a context of '/war2'. This war2 has a servlet url-mapping of '/servlet2' inside it.

```
EAR1---- WAR 1 --- Servlet1
EAR2---- WAR 2 --- Servlet2
```

Now, I need to forward request from servlet1 to servlet 2...So, Inside servlet1, I am trying to forwrd the request this way..

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/war2/servlet2").forward(request, response);
```

but it is failing..

how do I forward request to servlet2 that is in war2 that is in EAR2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that since the RequestDispatcher lives on the ServletContext, you won't be able to forward to a different servlet.  What error do you get?

It says here:

http://java.boot.by/wcd-guide/ch03s05.html

> "The ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher method takes a String
>   argument describing a path within the scope of the ServletContext."

See this post for more information:

[ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher() vs ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411114/servletcontext-getrequestdispatcher-vs-servletrequest-getrequestdispatcher)

Comment: Intresting...but when I try to forward the request in jsp using href='/war2/servlet2', it is forwarding it right....not sure what the difference here is?

Answer (score 0):

As per your description,you have two war files(`war1`,and `war2`),so it means you are having `two` context in same server.

In order to access the resource in different context you can do below.

```
ServletContext ctx = request.getServletContext().getContext("/war2");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ctx.getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: I can see that the request dispatcher for 'servlet2' is beind constructed fine...but after that the forward does not seem to be forwarding it..

Answer (score 0):

I do it with HttpUrlConnection as below:

```
// variable methodType is GET or POST in method call below

private void sendToAnotherServletInDifferentWar(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String methodType) throws IOException
    {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
       
        // replace/modify the path as per the path you want to hit.

        String pathToAnotherServlet = "http://localhost:8080/<war2-context>/<servlet-path>/<path-Info>";
        final URL url = new URL(pathToAnotherServlet);

        try
        {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(methodType);

            final Enumeration<String> headers = request.getHeaderNames();
            while (headers.hasMoreElements())
            {
                final String header = headers.nextElement();
                final Enumeration<String> values = request.getHeaders(header);
                while (values.hasMoreElements())
                {
                    final String value = values.nextElement();
                    System.out.println("header-> " + header + ": value-> " + value);
                    conn.addRequestProperty(header, value);
                }
            }

            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(false);
            conn.connect();

            final byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024];

            response.setStatus(conn.getResponseCode());
            System.out.println("HTTP Response Code obtained from service " + conn.getResponseCode());
            if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK)
            {
                for (int i = 0; ; ++i)
                {
                    final String header = conn.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
                    if (header == null)
                        break;
                    final String value = conn.getHeaderField(i);
                    response.setHeader(header, value);
                }

                while (true)
                {
                    final int read = conn.getInputStream().read(buffer);
                    if (read <= 0)
                        break;
                    response.getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            }
            else {
                response.sendError(conn.getResponseCode(), conn.getResponseMessage());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            logger.error("Calling service Failed with cause ", e);
            if(conn != null)
                response.sendError(conn.getResponseCode(), e.getMessage());
            else
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```