# What is the difference between different ways of creating RequestDispatcher Object?

Tags: jsp, servlets, web-applications, requestdispatcher

There are different ways of creating a RequestDispatcher Object:

Method 1: Using HttpRequest Object

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher();
```

Method 2: Using ServletContext Object

```
RequestDispatcher rd=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher();
```

Method 3: Using ServletContext & ServletConfig Object

```
RequestDispatcher rd =getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher();
```

What are the differences between these 3 methods and which one should i prefer to call a JSP page from a servlet/JSP in a dynamic web-app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher() vs ServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411114/servletcontext-getrequestdispatcher-vs-servletrequest-getrequestdispatcher)

Comment: There's only 2 method, `getServletConfig().getServletContext()` is just same as `getServletContext()`. Please see this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411114/servletcontext-getrequestdispatcher-vs-servletrequest-getrequestdispatcher)